# How to assign a nested property of an object given an array of keys

Tags: javascript

I have an object that resembles this:

```
const obj = {
   prop1: {
      prop2: {
         value: 'something',
         ...otherProps
      }
   },
   ...otherProps
}
```

And an array that looks like this:

```
const history = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'value']
```

How do I assign the property `value` of `prop2` a new value in a way that would also work for any other depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the property list and get each property of the object.

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      value: 'something'
    }
  }
};

const history = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'value'];

console.log(setPropertyValue(obj, history, "test"));
console.log(getPropertyValue(obj, history));

function getPropertyValueContainer(values, propertyList) {
  var copy = propertyList.slice(), propertyName = copy.pop();
  for (var property of copy) values = values[property];
  return { propertyName: propertyName, values: values };
}

function getPropertyValue(values, propertyList) {
  var container = getPropertyValueContainer(values, propertyList);
  return container.values[container.propertyName];
}

function setPropertyValue(values, propertyList, value) {
  var container = getPropertyValueContainer(values, propertyList);
  return container.values[container.propertyName] = value;
}
```

Comment: My intention is to reassign the value within the object

Comment: @StefanWullems Edited the answer, made a system that can do both

Answer (score 0):

You can use references.

So here i am taking reference of object in a variable untill i key equal to value and than adding value using that ref.

```js
const obj = { prop1: { prop2: { value: 'something'}}}

const history = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'value']
let ref = obj;

history.forEach((e,index)=>{
  if(e !== 'value' ) ref = ref[e]  
})

ref.value = 'xyz'

console.log(obj)
```